# list of keyvalue pair into dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary

I have a list of data as key value pair say for example:

```
[0,"test"],
[1,"test1"],
[2,"test2"],
[0,"test5"],
[1,"test1"]
```

I just want to add this set of data into key-value pair as two individual set as follows

```
keyvaluepair1 =>[0,"test"],
[1,"test1"],
[2,"test2"],
keyvaluepair2 => [0,"test5"],
[1,"test1"]
```

Comment: Please explicitly state the criteria separsting the two collections

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is that your key reverts to 0, then loop through the list and add a new dictionary to a list every time it resets.

```
//Your collection of KV Pair sets
var listOfKvs = new List<Dictionary<int,string>()

//an accumulator for the current set
var currentKvs = new Dictionary<int,string>()
var first = true;

foreach (var kv in keyvalues)
{
   //The condition for when your key resets
   if (kv.Key == 0)
   {
        if (first)
        {
            //we don't store the first dicitonary because it should be empty
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            listOfKvs.Add(currentKvs);
        }
        currentKvs = new Dictionary<int, string>()
   }

   currentKvs.add(kv);
}

//Store the last dictionary
listOfKvs.add(currentKvs);
```